# Can't access snowflake cloud panel

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

Please note that I'm totally new user of snowflake. The below question may seems silly to many.

I just set up a trial account with snowflake. The problem is that it is always logging me in at app.snowflake.com (instead of my cloud instance). Below one,

[image]

How can I access the standard interface? Below one,

[image]

Am I missing something on the configuration end?

Comment: The app.snowflake.com is just Snowflake's new interface.  It's still in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link to switch to Classical UI but it's not visible anymore for trial accounts.

So you should go to the "profile page" and change "Default Experience" to "Classical UI". Logout and login again.

[image]

Comment: I tried the above setting but didn't help. I also cleared the browser cache after the setting change. Possibly some limit on the trial account?

Comment: Ahh... finally I got classic UI. I had to log in with https://<account-name>.snowflakecomputing.com URL after the above setting changes. Earlier by default, it was just app.snowflake.com